# Conditional Expectation of Sum of Uniforms

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I'm having trouble with the following questions:

Suppose $X,Y$ ~ $U(0,1)$. Find $E[X^2|X+Y]$ and $E[XY|X+Y]$.

So far, I have: $E[X^2|X+Y] = \int x^2 f_{xy|x+y=z}$
Similarly: $E[XY|X+Y] = \int xy f_{xy|x+y=z}$

Furthermore: $f_{xy|x+y=z} = P((X=x,Y=y)\cap(X+Y =z))/P(X+Y =z)$

I'm lost on what: 1. The conditional density should be and 2. What the bounds of integration should be on both expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z=X+Y$. Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the joint density of $X$ and $Z$ is 
$$ f(x,z)=1_{0\leq x\leq 1, x\leq z\leq x+1}$$
and the density of $Z$ is $f_Z(z)=z$ if $0\leq z\leq 1$, $f_Z(z)=2-z$ if $1\leq z\leq 2$. These densities can be computed by finding the areas of appropriate regions in the unit square, then differentiating.

Next, by defintion
$$ \mathbb{E}[X^2|Z=z]=\int x^2f_{X|Z}(x|z)\;dx=\frac{1}{f_Z(z)}\int x^2f(x,z)\;dx $$

If $0\leq z\leq 1$ this integral becomes
$$ \frac{1}{z}\int_0^z x^2\;dx=\frac{z^2}{3} $$
while if $1\leq z\leq 2$ it becomes
$$ \frac{1}{2-z}\int_{z-1}^1x^2\;dx=\frac{z^2-z+1}{3} $$
(after some simplifications).

By symmetry, $\mathbb{E}[Y^2|Z]=\mathbb{E}[X^2|Z]$. And since $\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^2|Z]=Z^2$ and $(X+Y)^2=X^2+2XY+Y^2$, we can use the work we've already done to determine $\mathbb{E}[XY|Z]$.

Comment: Why are we justified from going from $f_{xy|x+y=z}$ to $f_{xz|z}$? Are these the same conditional distributions?

Comment: In fact, this is a general problem I'm having -- I select the wrong measures. I thought the way to get the conditional probability was to take the joint density (x,y) intersected with the restriction, divided by the probability of the restriction. (IE $f_{xy|x+y=z} = P((X=x,Y=y)\cap(X+Y =z))/P(X+Y =z)$) But you created a joint distribution between whatever was on the LHS and RHS of the conditioning bar. Are these both equivalent?

Comment: @yoshi Strictly speaking, the conditional pdf are $~f_{X\mid X+Y=z}(x) ~$ and $~ f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)~$ and since $Z=X+Y$ these are indeed alternate representations of the same conditional pdf. &nbsp; (Note this is case sensitive; capitalisation matters)

Comment: @GrahamKemp I can't edit my first post!! But yes thank you.

Comment: @carmichael561 Also, should the total expectation E[X^2|Z]  = E[X^2|Z, 0<Z<1] P(0<Z<1) + E[X^2|Z, 1<Z<2] P(1<Z<2). Both the probabilities are 1/2 so the total expectation is the average of the two computations you made?

Comment: @yoshi On the other matter, under the condition that $X+Y=z$ then $X$ and $Y$ are linearly dependent ($Y=z-X$). $~$ So we do not double integrate over the joint support; we must integrate over the condition line. $$f_{X,Y\mid X+Y}(x,y\mid z) = f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)~\delta_{z-x}(y)$$

Comment: @yoshi No you don't take the average.  The expectation is a random variable that is a piecewise function of the $Z$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I didn't follow what you were saying about integrating over the conditioning line, would you be willing to chat?